# (Python) Distributing numbers equally

Tags: python

I apologize for the title. If someone can think of more descriptive title, please tell me and I will repost this question, or edit the title. (if possible)
Hello, I am currently working on a game. When there is an attack initiated, the attacker has a potential resource number that he can get from the other player. I'm having trouble figuring out how to evenly distribute these resources for the attacker, if the defender has the resources to give.

```
#this is how many resources the attacker can get, def's resources
attacker_potential = 250
#this is how many resources the defender has
defender.wood = 100
defender.iron = 25
defender.wheat = 76
defender.gold = 50000
#then the attacker would make off with 
attacker.wood += 75
attacker.iron += 25
attacker.wheat += 75
attacker.gold += 75
```

Another example:

```
defender.wood = 2500
defender.iron = 2500
defender.wheat = 5000
defender.gold = 5000
#here, the attacker would make off with 62 for each resource. (250 / 4 = 62.5)
```

Here is another example:

```
defender.wood = 100
defender.iron = 0
defender.wheat = 1
defender.gold = 0
#attacker would make off with:
attacker.wood += 100
attacker.iron += 0
attacker.wheat += 1
attacker.gold += 0
```

And then one final example:

```
defender.wood = 50000 #pretend the rest are 0
attacker.wood += 250
```

(ocne I figure out how many resources the attacker gets, the rest of the math is easy). 
I just reached this point in my code, and I spent a good 20 minutes trying to figure out how it would work. I have a feeling that the answer can be very easy, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round Robin for integer resources. If you really want to split resources you can check if the total amount of remaining resources is smaller than the number of resources and split evenly.

```
def distribute(potential, defender_resources):
    attacker_resources = [0] * len(defender_resources)

    while potential and any(defender_resources):
        for i in range(len(defender_resources)):
            if potential and defender_resources[i]:
                defender_resources[i] -= 1
                attacker_resources[i] += 1
                potential -= 1

    return attacker_resources

print distribute(250, [100,0,1,0])
print distribute(250, [100,25,76,5000])
print distribute(250, [2500,2500,2500,2500])
print distribute(250, [5000])
```

Comment: -1 -- This is linear in the potential, i.e. it's a really *bad* solution. Everybody would expect `distribute(10, [10])` to take about the same time as `distribute(10**12, [10**12])`. Your solution takes *hours* in the second case, while it is instantaneous in the first case.

Comment: I found this solution to be much easier to follow than the other one, however, if there are decimals, I have noticed that it will break it, which was easily fixed with just using round(). Thank you for the solution.

Answer (score 3):

One algorithm that is consistent with the examples you presented is the following:

1. Let the average loot be the attacker's potential divided by the number of the defender's non-zero resources. Loop through the defender's non-zero resources and if any of them are less than or equal to the average loot, remove them from the defender and give them to the attacker.
2. If during step 1 resources less than or equal to the average loot were encountered and moved, recompute the average loot and repeat step 1. Otherwise, proceed to step 3.
3. Finally, if the defender has any resources left, simply recompute the average loot and remove it from every resource (giving them to the attacker).

A possible implementation in python follows:

```
def step1(dres, aloot, potential):

    again = False

    ndres = {}

    if len(dres) > 0:

        avgloot = int(potential / len(dres))

        for r in dres:
            if dres[r] <= avgloot:
                potential -= dres[r]
                aloot[r] += dres[r]
                again = True
            else:
                ndres[r] = dres[r]

    return (ndres, aloot, potential, again)

def calculate_loot(dres, potential):

    aloot = {'wood':0, 'iron':0, 'wheat':0, 'gold':0}

    (dres, aloot, potential, again) = step1(dres, aloot, potential)

    while again:
        (dres, aloot, potential, again) = step1(dres, aloot, potential)

    if len(dres) > 0:
        avgloot = int(potential / len(dres))
        for r in dres:
            aloot[r] += avgloot

    return aloot

potential = 250

for dres in [
        {'wood':100,  'iron':25,   'wheat':76,   'gold':50000},
        {'wood':2500, 'iron':2500, 'wheat':5000, 'gold':5000 },
        {'wood':100,  'iron':0,    'wheat':1,    'gold':0    },
        {'wood':0,    'iron':0,    'wheat':0,    'gold':50000}
    ]:

    print(dres)
    print(calculate_loot(dres, potential))
    print(' ')
```

[Online Demo](http://ideone.com/1S2QMQ)